# How to add EventListener to an html link?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, electron, addeventlistener

EventListener is not added and test code is not executed when instead of standard html button `<input type="button"></input>` I refer to `<a></a>` in the renderer.js:

```
//code here is executed
...
window.user_button = document.querySelector('#lbUserButton')
user_button.addEventListener('Click', ()=>{
    //code here is not executed
    event.preventDefault();
    ipc.send('event-name');        
})
```

HTML:

```
<a id="lbUserButton" href="#" class="someCssClass">
    button title
</a>
```

Comment: Are you using electron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is not executed because you've added an event listener for "Click" while it should be lowercase "click". The code below will work.

```js
user_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var user_button = document.queryselector('#lbUserButton')
```

I don't know if you have already defined user_button, maybe you forgot. If you are defining it, why put `window.` before it? I don't think that is necessary. At least, I never put it.